# Bootstrap Carousel doesn't work propely

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span8">
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel  slide">

  <!-- Carousel items -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="active item"><img src="01.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="02.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="03.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="02.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="03.jpg" alt=""></div>
  </div>

  <!-- Carousel nav -->
  <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
  <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
</div>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am working on site based on [this theme](http://bootstrapwp.rachelbaker.me/).
When I put Bootstrap Carousel it's jumping on the last frame and shows nothing. I have read many tutorials and couldn't understand what I did wrong. I following the theme instruction.

My site is [here](http://shopogolick.16mb.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the provided URL, you have an empty `p` element inside `.carousel-inner`. Try removing that.

Comment: gregory, thank you! I got. But i dont know how and where i can remove that. In css i see nothing similar inside carousel-inner. Where i can remove <p> in php, i am not much familiar with php. Thank you!

Comment: how is that page (http://shopogolick.16mb.com/) generated? is it plain html or is there a content management system behind it? Basically you have to find the file or the location where the carousel is rendered and search for that empty `p` element.

Comment: There are actually two `</p>`, one before the slights list and one after, both of them may be the reason

Comment: thank you for your advice! My page is generated from this WP bootstrap framework https://github.com/rachelbaker/bootstrapwp-Twitter-Bootstrap-for-WordPress/tree/1-WIP and i followed instraction from this http://bootstrapwp.rachelbaker.me/javascript-guide/ and with other styles its okey, but this Carousel no. Could you tell me in what file i should delete or how i can find this file?

Comment: Wherever you wrote the carousel html is most likely where the <p> tags are going to be.

Comment: I saw by Coogle Canary this: user agent stylesheet and code p {
display: block;
-webkit-margin-before: 1em;
-webkit-margin-after: 1em;
-webkit-margin-start: 0px;
-webkit-margin-end: 0px;
} there is no this <p> in css style

Comment: This has nothing to do with CSS. As @MobyD pointed out, you have to find the file where the carousel is inserted. Or, if you wrote that code directly into the Rich Text Editor in Wordpress, check if the `p` was inserted automatically.

Comment: i created a static page as the main page, then put code (above) on page in WP console, thats all. I didnt write anything by myself, just put classes from css.. so, i cant understand where i should seach for <p>. I am begginer in php.. i use this template for page

Comment: The Rich Text Editor (WP console) sometimes inserts `p` paragraphs. Switch from "Visual" mode to "HTML" mode and see if there are any line breaks that could cause automatic inserting of parameters. See this image: http://www.totalbounty.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/disable-wordpress-visual-editor1.png.png

Comment: Gregory, thank you very much! You are completely right! I noticed empty space in Visual mode and deleted it and now its working okay! Thank you!)

Answer (score 1):

looks like `<p>` tag is giving problem... `<p>` tag is closing with every "img and div" tags in the end.Try to find `<p>` tag in your file and remove it.